# Клонирование системы на ssd

Tags: windows, администрирование, ssd, clone

Воспользовавшись "Acronis true image wd edition"
Склонировал диск на ssd(wd green) с автоматической конфигурацией.
Как итог флажок windows на темном экране и кружок загрузки, индикатор обращения к диску мигает.
Почему так?

Comment: Откуда скопировал?

Comment: @donRumata c hdd

Answer (score 1):

Прочел инструкцию к программе, оказалось что после клонирования надо отключить исходный диск, оставив лишь целевой.
После данной манипуляции и очередного клонирования все заработало!